# How are dates stored in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, date

How are dates stored in Oracle? For example I know most systems use Epoch time to determine what time it is. By calculating how many seconds away from January 1st 1970. Does Oracle do  this as well?

The reason I am asking this is I noticed if you take two dates in Oracle and subtract them you get a floating point of how many days are between.

Example

```
(Sysdate - dateColumn)
```

would return something like this (depending on the time)

```
3.32453703703703703703703703703703703704
```

Now is Oracle doing the conversion and spitting that format out, or does Oracle store dates with how many days it is away from a certain time frame? (Like Epoch time)

Comment: I wonder how many bits you'd need to store Unix timestamps in the -4713 to 9999 range...

Comment: @AlvaroGonzalez: that would be 14711 years. How many seconds in that many years? If we say there are 365.25 days in a year then there are 31557600 seconds in a year, which means there are 464,243,853,600 seconds in 14711 years. So a 39 bit value (max = 549,755,813,888) would handle it. A 64 bit number would handle it for the forseeable (out to roughly the year 584,542,041,377) future :-).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There are two types 12 and 13

http://oraclesniplets.tumblr.com/post/1179958393/my-oracle-support-oracle-database-69028-1

**Type 13**

```
select dump(sysdate) from dual;
Typ=13 Len=8: 220,7,11,26,16,41,9,0

The format of the date datatype is

Byte 1 - Base 256 year modifier : 220
2      - Base 256 year : 256 * 7 = 1792 + 220 = 2012
3      - Month : 11
4      - Day : 26
5      - Hours : 16
6      - Minutes : 41
7      - Seconds : 09
8      - Unused
```

2012-11-26 16:41:09

**Type 12**

```
select dump(begindate) from tab;
Typ=12 Len=7: 100,112,2,7,1,1,1

The format of the date datatype is

byte 1 - century (excess 100)  100 - 100 = 00
byte 2 - year (excess 100)  112 - 100 = 12
byte 3 - month = 2
byte 4 - day = 7
byte 5 - hour (excess 1) 1 - 1 = 0
byte 6 - minute (excess 1) 1 - 1 = 0
byte 7 - seconds (excess 1) 1 - 1 = 0
```

0012-02-07 00:00:00

Answer (score 6):

From the manual at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#sthref151

> *For each DATE value, Oracle stores the following information: year, month, day, hour, minute, and second*

So apparently it's not storing an epoch value which is also confirmed by [this chapter of the manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/tablecls.htm#CBBGJHJC):

> *The database stores dates internally as numbers. Dates are stored in fixed-length fields of 7 bytes each, corresponding to century, year, month, day, hour, minute, and second*

Comment: Very interesting, Thank You!  I was sorta hoping it used Julian date for storing the date. This method probably makes more sense anyway!

Comment: @Halfwarr: why do you care how it's stored? That does not matter at all.

Comment: Just wanted to know, no real reason. I was just curious how they are stored because I was working with them. You can never have enough random knowledge ;)

Answer (score 6):

> How are dates stored in Oracle?

The **two data types** `12` and `13` are for two different purposes.

- **Type 12** - Dates stored in table
- **Type 13** - Date returned by internal date functions like `SYSDATE`/`CURRENT_DATE`, also when converting a string literal into date using `TO_DATE` or **ANSI Date literal** `DATE 'YYYY-MM-DD'`.

**Test cases:**

Basic table setup for **type 12**:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t(col DATE);

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t SELECT SYSDATE FROM dual;

1 row created.

SQL> COMMIT;

Commit complete.
```

Check the different cases:

```
SQL> SELECT DUMP(col) FROM t;

DUMP(COL)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Typ=12 Len=7: 120,116,3,17,18,6,55

SQL> SELECT DUMP(SYSDATE) FROM dual;

DUMP(SYSDATE)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Typ=13 Len=8: 224,7,3,17,17,5,54,0

SQL> SELECT DUMP(CURRENT_DATE) FROM dual;

DUMP(CURRENT_DATE)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Typ=13 Len=8: 224,7,3,17,17,14,20,0

SQL> SELECT DUMP(TO_DATE('17-DEC-1980 12:12:12','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))  FROM dual;

DUMP(TO_DATE('17-DEC-198012:12:12','
------------------------------------
Typ=13 Len=8: 188,7,12,17,12,12,12,0
```

Using **ANSI Date literal**, just like **TO_DATE**:

```
SQL> SELECT DUMP(DATE '2016-03-17') FROM dual;

DUMP(DATE'2016-03-17')
--------------------------------
Typ=13 Len=8: 224,7,3,17,0,0,0,0

SQL> INSERT INTO t SELECT to_date('17-DEC-1980 12:13:14','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM dual;

1 row created.

SQL> COMMIT;

Commit complete.

SQL> SELECT DUMP(col) FROM t;

DUMP(COL)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Typ=12 Len=7: 120,116,3,17,18,6,55
Typ=12 Len=7: 119,180,12,17,13,14,15

SQL>
```

As you can see, while storing a date in the table, it uses **type 12**. The second **type 13** is used when converting a string literal into date using date functions or when date returned by internal date functions like `SYSDATE`/`CURRENT_DATE`.