# PL/SQL treating date differently in SQL hard code

Tags: oracle, date, plsql

I developed a simple query to place in a pl/sql procedure. Through Toad I can pass in my two variables and it preforms perfectly, but for some reason when I place it in the procedure, it fails.  I have tried numerous techniques but the only solution is to hard code the date, which defeats the whole purpose.

Inputs

```
DECLARE
   D_PROJECT_ID  NUMBER := 32311;
   END_DATE  DATE := '31-JAN-2015';
   ETC_BDLB NUMBER := 0;
   ETC_BDEC NUMBER := 0;
   ETC_BDLC NUMBER := 0;
```

Problem child, the first option is the only one which will work.

```
and to_date(b2.attribute2,'DD-MON-YYYY') <= '31-JAN-2015'); RETURNS $$$
                                          and to_date(b2.attribute2,'DD-MON-YYYY') <= END_DATE); --RETURNS 0  END_DATE VARCHAR2(11)
                                          and to_date(b2.attribute2,'DD-MON-YYYY') <= END_DATE); --RETURNS 0 END DATE AS DATE
                                          and to_date(b2.attribute2,'DD-MON-YYYY') <= TRUNC(END_DATE)); --RETURNS 0
                                          and to_date(b2.attribute2,'DD-MON-YYYY') <= TO_DATE(END_DATE, 'DD-MON-YY'));  --RETURNS 0
and to_date(b2.attribute2,'DD-MON-YYYY') <= TO_DATE(END_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY'));  --RETURNS 0
```

DEBUG OUTPUT:

```
[--- 1 ---]

[1] D_PROJECT_ID = 32311
[1] END_DATE = 31-JAN-15
[1] ETC_BDLB = 0
[1] ETC_BDEC = 0
[1] ETC_BDLC = 0
```

I will try any options.

Comment: Allready tried to assign a date explicitly casted in the declare part: END_DATE  DATE := `to_date( '31-01-2015', DD-MM-YYYY);`, so that you can be sure `END_DATE`contains the desired date?

Comment: I am assuming the second parameter should have single quotes.  It gave me the same results.  I can tell the date is correct based upon the variable print statements.

Comment: What are your `attribute2` values? What is your NLS_DATE_FORMAT?

Comment: attribute2 stores the date I am comparing, it is a varchar field in the table.  The table is a seeded oracle table.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
DECLARE
  END_DATE  DATE;
...
BEGIN
  END_DATE  := TO_DATE ('31-JAN-2015');
...
END ;
```

Comment: Can you Please provide some examples? select to_date(b2.attribute2) from b2;

Comment: attribute2 contains data like this:30-JUN-2013
31-JUL-2013
31-AUG-2013
30-SEP-2013
31-OCT-2013
30-NOV-2013
31-DEC-2013
31-JAN-2014
28-FEB-2014
31-MAR-2014

Comment: Are you aware of the fact, that a date not only contains  day, month, year values, but the hours, minutes and seconds, too? If you create a new date with just providing some of these values, '31-JAN-2015' <= '31-JAN-2015' is not always true. 
1. as already described, please ensure to set dates with to_date(string, format_string) 
2. check the complete date value to anlyze your code, use to_char(date_value, format_string)

a = '31-JAN-2015', b = '31-JAN-2015'
?: a <= b
to_char(a,'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24-MM-SS') = '2015-01-31-09-15-44'
to_char(b,'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24-MM-SS') = '2015-01-31-06-20-22'
a > b

Answer (score 1):

For a `DATE` literal you have to use this format (only)

```
DATE '2015-01-31'
```

Time fractions are not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Always remember these 2 basic rules when handling dates -

1. Never assign a string to a `DATE` variable and expect it to work
2. Never compare a string variable with a `DATE` variable.

You might be able to make it work sometimes but this practice should never go into production code. It's a pain for the DBA in the long run.

In the code above, both these rules are broken.

```
END_DATE  DATE := '31-JAN-2015';
```

The left side is a variable of type DATE and the right side is a string (Yes DD-MON-YYYY doesn't make it a date, it is still a string). This should have been

```
END_DATE  DATE := TO_DATE('31-JAN-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY');
```

Also,

```
to_date(b2.attribute2,'DD-MON-YYYY') <= '31-JAN-2015'
```

This is a comparison between a DATE on the left and a string on the right. Should've been

```
to_date(b2.attribute2,'DD-MON-YYYY') <= to_date('31-JAN-2015','DD-MON-YYYY);
```

When you pass in parameters into a procedure, you might pass a `VARCHAR2` in an agreed upon format, but before assigning it to a DATE variable though, convert it into `DATE` using the `TO_DATE` function.

Oracle internally stores dates as 7bytes or 8bytes depending on the implementation. [See this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568193/how-are-dates-stored-in-oracle) So it doesn't make sense to compare a string that says `'31-JAN-2015'` to a date type that probably has these 8 bytes - `[223,7,1,31,0,0,0,0]`. You would first need to convert that string into a date type with that same format of 8 bytes (or 7) and then compare them.

There is another parameter that comes into play here that is NLS_DATE_FORMAT. The only reason this exists is that whenever you compare a string and a date; OR try to assign a string into a date, before it returns a datatype mismatch error, oracle will do you a favor and check to see if that string follows the format specified in this parameter. If it does, then oracle will do the `to_date` behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

While I would not recommend my solution, I changed the input parameter to a varchar2 instead of a date.  The date in the database is being stored as a varchar2 as well, and both variables are going through a to_date function before the comparison.