# Oracle: convert varchar2 to the datetime format 'yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ssZ'

Tags: oracle, datetime

I have a date in a varchar2 with format 'ddmmyyyy' and I want to convert it to the format 'yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ssZ' in which the final variable has a date time format.

For instance, I have the following varchar2 variable `variable1`:

`variable1 := '11092016'`;

and I want the final result be:

`variable2:='2016-09-11T00:00:00Z'`

where `variable2` is not a varchar2 but has other any date time format.

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: What does "date2 is not a varchar2 but has other any date time format" mean?  You can either have a string in a particular format that represents a date, in which case you'd have a `varchar2` or you can have a `date` or a `timestamp` neither of which has a format.

Comment: Note `Z` means time zone `UTC` - is this the case or do you need a conversion?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit yes it is time zone UTC...I want to convert to it having a varchar2 as 'variable1'

Comment: @JustinCave I have edited my post to be more clearly what I want to do

Comment: I'm still confused.  Do you want `variable2` to be a `varchar2`?  A `date`?  A `timestamp with time zone`?  Something else?  A `varchar2` has a format.  A `date` or a `timestamp` does not.  You say "variable2 is not a varchar2 but has other any date time format" but that still doesn't make sense.

Comment: See [How are dates stored in Oracle?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13568348/1509264) for details of what a `DATE` is in Oracle and you will see that asking it to have a specific format is nonsensical. If you want a specific format then you will need to convert it to a string or tell your client software how to convert it to a string (usually with the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` parameter - but this is a user variable and subject to change).

Answer (score 2):

Dates do not have a format. The format is either applied by converting them to a string or by the client software. If you just want it as a date then use `TO_DATE( value, 'DDMMYYYY' )` (and the date object will have a time component set to `00:00:00`) but if you want it as an ISO8601 formatted string:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE dates ( value ) AS
SELECT '20032016' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         TO_DATE( value, 'DDMMYYYY' ),
         'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"'
       ) AS ISODate
FROM   dates;
```

**Output**:

```
ISODATE
--------------------
2016-03-20T00:00:00Z
```

Comment: ISODATE will be a varchar, won't have a date time format..right?

Comment: See my edit - dates do not have a format (they are represented internally by either 7 or 8 bytes, depending on how they are created). If you want a date to have a format then you need to convert it to a string (either within oracle or within the client you are using to perform the queries).

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
Select to_char (current_timestamp,'yyyy-MM-dd"T"HH:mm:sss"Z"') from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case of having this result, I used this

TO_char(date,'YYYY-MM-DD"''T''"HH24:MI:SS."000-0500"') on datagrip with Oracle source.

Mu result: 2020-03-01'T'23:40:34.000-0500