# Date format in where clause-Oracle

Tags: oracle, where-clause, date-format

I have one table where date column is having data in below format:
"7/25/2014 12:14:27 AM'. I need to fetch this date by putting in the where clause. can anyone suggest how can i do this?

Comment: A date column does not have a format; is it a date or a varchar column?

Answer (score 13):

Dates (stored in tables) are [represented by 7 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13568348/1509264) - they do not have any format associated with them. If they are formatted as a string then that is the client program which you are using to access the database applying its own formatting to the date (which you can usually set via the preferences in that program).

If the "date" is stored with a format then you are not storing it as a date but storing it as a string (i.e. `VARCHAR2`) format.

**Query - if the date is stored as a date**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  date_column = TO_DATE( '7/25/2014 12:14:27 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM' )
```

or, using ANSI/ISO literals:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  date_column = TIMESTAMP '2014-07-25 00:14:27'
```

or, if you want values which are just for a given day then:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  date_column >= DATE '2016-05-12'
AND    date_column <  DATE '2016-05-13'
```

*(This will allow you to use any indexes on the `date_column` column.)*

or, only passing a single day value (represented by the bind variable `:date_value`):

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  date_column >= :date_value
AND    date_column <  :date_value + INTERVAL '1' DAY
```

**Query - if the "date" is stored as a string**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  TO_DATE( date_as_a_string_column, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM' )
         = TIMESTAMP '2014-07-25 00:14:27'
```

or, just simply:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  date_as_a_string_column = '7/25/2014 12:14:27 AM'
```

Comment: Hi Got the answer after doing some google, below query worked fine: where TO_CHAR(RECORD_UPDATE_DT, 'MM/DD/YYYY') = '05/12/2016'

Thanks for the time.

Comment: @HemantSingh While it will work, it will also disregard any indexes you have on the column (unless you have a function-based index on `TO_CHAR(RECORD_UPDATE_DT, 'MM/DD/YYYY')`) so it will be less performant. It is better to convert the right-hand side (i.e. the literal value) to a date.

Answer (score 5):

Most likely the date format you see is the format your SQL tool (SQLplus, SQL Developer, Toad etc.) uses. Proper date columns don't have an associated date format.

To write a reliable query for selecting by date, explicitly specify the date format in your query (otherwise Oracle we use the date format from your current session):

```
SELECT * FROM T1
WHERE DATE_COL > TO_DATE('7/25/2014 12:14:27 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM');
```

Any other date format will also work:

```
SELECT * FROM T1
WHERE DATE_COL > TO_DATE('2014-07-25 12:14:27', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');
```

Comment: Hi Got the answer after doing some google, below query worked fine:


where TO_CHAR(RECORD_UPDATE_DT, 'MM/DD/YYYY') = '05/12/2016'.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: If your date column has an index, your query won't be able to use it because you compare to a value derived from the date column. If you want to make use of the index, look at the MT0's or my answer.