# Oracle : Date time subtraction

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have to calculate time difference in minutes from current(**sysdate**) and **modified** time:-

```
to_date(to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
- to_date(to_char(modified, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

but problem is *to_char* returns proper time:-

```
to_char(whenmodified, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

Outputs `2016-05-23 14:55:50`

and *to_date* doesn’t show time:-

```
to_date(to_char(modified, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

Outputs: `2016-05-23`

Please assist how I can get time difference by converting to_char to to_date.

NOTE:

1. I cant do **sysdate-modified** because both sysdate and modified gives date without time e.g     2016-05-23
2. Using to_char for sysdate or modified give date with time        2016-05-23 14:55:50
3. As we cant subtracts dates in to_char function I am again converting back them to to_date for getting time.

I am expecting:
2016-05-23 14:55:50 - 2016-05-23 14:53:50 = 2 min

Comment: Why are you converting `sysdate` and `modified` to text and back again?

Comment: can you not just do sysdate-modified ?

Comment: no, because sysdate or modified just gives date but no time stamp

Comment: @JonSkeet, because to_date(whenmodified, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') gives  only date 2016-05-23 and I need time difference too.

Comment: whats the data type of modified ?

Comment: Your question is really unclear at the moment. It would help if you'd show your schema, sample data and expected results.

Comment: @cableload, its DATE

Comment: @JonSkeet, I have updated question

Comment: You still haven't told us the type of `modified` in your schema...

Comment: Its Date, mentioned already above for cableload's question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have to calculate time difference in minutes from current(sysdate) and modified time

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( modified DATE );

INSERT INTO table_name
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2016-05-23 14:20:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2016-05-23 00:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2016-05-01 00:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2016-01-01 00:00:00' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT ( sysdate - modified ) * 24 * 60 AS minute_difference
FROM   table_name;
```

**Output**:

```
MINUTE_DIFFERENCE
-----------------
       3.66666667 
       863.666667 
       32543.6667 
       206783.667
```

And to address your comment that:

> to_date doesn’t show time

A date **always** has a time component and **never** has a format internally to the database (it is represented by [7 or 8 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13568348/1509264)) - the formatting of a date is done by the client program that you use to access the database (and often the default is not to show the time component - however, the time component still exists).

You can change this either in the preferences of your client program or, if they don't use that to control it, by changing the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
```

Comment: not sure what it does exactly, I am working on prod data. Do I need to run ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'; before running my select query? will if affect other any things, please let me know

Comment: and important thing is I just have read only access to database

Comment: @nilFi: As MT0 said: The date is a datetime really, and you can format it according to your wishes in your app when you want to display it. (I guess there is an app, because you say you are reading production data.) If you are using an app that uses the Oracle setting NLS_DATE_FORMAT in order to display a datetime and you cannot change that setting, then you can use TO_CHAR to specify the desired format in your query. You know that function already.

Comment: @nilFi Try it yourself on a non-production database `SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE` then `STARTUP MOUNT` then `ALTER DATABASE OPEN READ ONLY` then `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'hh24 yyyy ss mi mm dd'`. It will work even though the DB is read-only and you will get the date in your very own weird format. Try connecting as a different user and they do not get your date format as session parameters are per-user.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner yes I can use TO_CHAR to specify desired format but can not do date time subtraction, where date are in text format.

Comment: @nilFi: Seems you haven't understood yet what MT0 told you. You store datetimes in an Oracle database in the DATE format; it consists of a date plus a time. You can add minutes, subtract seconds, compare datetimes, get the difference in days, minutes, hours, ... This has nothing to do with displaying the data. When you want to show a datetime specify the Format. Usually this is done in your app (e.g. in Java, PHP, whatever) and you decide there whether to show the date only or date plus time or time only...

Comment: ... Some apps (sqlplus, Toad, etc.) use the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` to decide how to display a datetime. So when you select `SYSDATE` for example, they take the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` and display the datetime accordingly. If you don't want this, then either change this setting or use `TO_CHAR` in your query to force a specific display (e.g. `TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'hh24:mi')`).

Comment: And anyway, a "time difference in minutes" is not a datetime, but a time interval. When subtracting two datetimes in Oracle you get the difference in days as a decimal number. You can multiply it to get hours, minutes or seconds, etc. as shown. Or use `numtodsinterval(<minutes>, 'minute')` to display the minutes as an interval.

Comment: The other alternative to get the difference between two times as an `INTERVAL` datatype is to cast both `DATE`s to `TIMESTAMP`s - like this: `SELECT CAST( SYSDATE AS TIMESTAMP ) - CAST( modified AS TIMESTAMP ) FROM table_name` which will output something like `+01 05:30:39.000000` as the days, hours, minutes and seconds between the two times.

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner thanks to notify  that thereis nothing to do with displaying the data. I was under impression that as I am unable to see time it means time is not associated with the fields :)