# Oracle SQL Date Ranges

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle11g

I have the following query:

```
select * from sa_tran_head WHERE
((TRAN_DATETIME) BETWEEN NVL(:STARTDATE, TRAN_DATETIME) AND NVL(:ENDDATE, TRAN_DATETIME));
```

If I put `STARTDATE = 21-JUN-2016 and ENDDATE = 21-JUN-2016`, it doesn't show anything.
When I put `STARTDATE = 21-JUN-2016 and ENDDATE = 22-JUN-2016`, it shows the results of 21-JUN-2016.

Why does it happen?

Answer (score 1):

My guess? `TRAN_DATETIME` also stores time value?

Use `TRUNC()` :

```
select * from sa_tran_head
WHERE TRUNC(TRAN_DATETIME) BETWEEN NVL(:STARTDATE, TRUNC(TRAN_DATETIME)) 
                               AND NVL(:ENDDATE, TRUNC(TRAN_DATETIME));
```

Comment: Using `TRUNC( TRAN_DATETIME )` will mean that any index on that column cannot be used. To use an index you would need a function-based index.

Comment: To use an index he can just use his current query with range between yesterday and today or something @MT0

Answer (score 0):

Datetime are internally treated as proper timestamp. When you mention date as `21-Jun-2016`, it is treated as `21-Jun-2016 00:00:00.000`. Hence, it is checking for the values in the `21-Jun-2016 00:00:00.000` and `21-Jun-2016 00:00:00.000` in the first condition, explaining the output you get.

Comment: Oracle does not have a `datetime` data type. It has `DATE` and `TIMESTAMP` and they both have a time component. The OP is talking about `DATE`s and these are not stored with millisecond accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

May be ignore hour, minutes and seconds?
Look at example:

```
create table t(v date)
/
insert into t(v) values(to_date('2016-06-23 23:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))
/
-- no rows
select * from t where
v BETWEEN Nvl(to_date('2016-06-23 08:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), v) 
    AND NVL(to_date('2016-06-23 08:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), v);
/
-- exactly one
select * from t where
v BETWEEN Nvl(to_date('2016-06-23 08:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), v) 
    AND NVL(to_date('2016-06-24 08:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), v);
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle stores dates in a [7- or 8-byte data structure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13568348/1509264) which **always** includes a time component.

When you have a date `TO_DATE( '21-JUN-2016', 'DD-MON-YYYY' )` then Oracle will create the date with the time `00:00:00`.

If you do:

```
WHERE TRAN_DATETIME BETWEEN TO_DATE( '21-JUN-2016 00:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS' )
                        AND TO_DATE( '21-JUN-2016 00:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS' )
```

Then you will only get results which are on the day you want **and** have the time component `00:00:00`.

Now you can use `TRUNC()` to set the time component to `00:00:00`:

```
WHERE TRUNC( TRAN_DATETIME ) BETWEEN DATE '2016-06-21' AND DATE '2016-06-21'
```

However, if there is an index on the `TRAN_DATETIME` column then this query will not use it (it could, however, use a function-based index on `TRUNC( TRAN_DATETIME )`).

A solution that can use the index is:

```
WHERE TRAN_DATETIME >= :start_date 
AND   TRAN_DATE     <  :end_date + INTERVAL '1' DAY
```

(Assuming that `:start_date` and `:end_date` are bind variable passed in with a time component of `00:00:00` - which is what you appear to be doing).

Incorporating the `NVL` statements:

```
WHERE ( :start_date IS NULL OR TRAN_DATETIME >= :start_date )
AND   ( :end_date   IS NULL OR TRAN_DATE     <  :end_date + INTERVAL '1' DAY )
```