# Convert yyyy/mm/dd into dd/mm/yyyy hh24:MI:SS

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to convert data in format `2016/06/26` into `26/06/2016 00:00:00`
I was trying few option all the time getting error "Invalid  months name",
Any idea/advice?
Thanks

```
select to_date('2016/05/07 00:00:00','mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MI:SS') from dual
```

Comment: My guess is that you are using a format string that includes month name instead of month number.

Comment: show us the command what indicated that error

Comment: Hello, I edited my answer

Comment: @user5506560 Why do you need to do this? What is the context around this requirement? E.g. where does the date information come from? Is it a file, or a table in the database? What will you do with the results? Are you going to insert the results into another table? Output the results for reporting purposes?

Comment: Just seen your edit: isn't there a clear mismatch between `2016/05/07` and `mm/dd/yyyy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to convert a string to a date you need to convert it first to a date. Your problems is that you are trying to format a string not a date. So for you specific case it would be:

```
--convert it first to a date
select to_date('2016/05/07 00:00:00','yyyy/mm/dd HH24:MI:SS') 
  from dual

--then convert it to a string in the format you want:
select to_char( to_date('2016/05/07 00:00:00','yyyy/mm/dd HH24:MI:SS'),
                'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MI:SS' )
  from dual

--since you want it as a date:

--then convert it to a string in the format you want:
select to_date( to_char( to_date('2016/05/07 00:00:00',
                                 'yyyy/mm/dd HH24:MI:SS'),
                         'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MI:SS' )
                'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MI:SS' ) 
  from dual
```

If you want just to convert your string into a date no matter the format, just use the first select I showed. Thanks to @Boneist in comments for pointing it out.

Comment: Thanks, but the issue is that at the end I need that value AS date type...

Comment: Then convert it to a date again.

Comment: I tried but I got error message date format picture ends before converting entire input string"

Comment: @JorgeCampos surely, if the OP wants their string as a date, then you just need the initial `to_date` - ie. no need to convert it to a string and then back to a date?

Comment: Hm, I tried you edited answer and the result is 16/05/07

Comment: @Boneist You are right. I thought that he just want to change the date format.

Comment: @user5506560 That's because your client configuration.

Comment: If you have converted it to a date once then you **do not** need to convert it to a string and back to a date again. Dates do not have a format (they are represented by [7- or 8-bytes internally to the database](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13568348/1509264)) and it only when they are passed to a client program and that client program translates it to whatever format it stores it in does it potentially get a format.