# converting yyyy-mm-dd into mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to convert YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MM:SS INTO MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MM:SS

The last try was :

```
SQL> select to_date(to_date('2016-05-01 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual
```

I got error which says :Invalid monhts, 
I'm very confused and tired of that, could anyone take a look ?

Comment: to_date expects a string input and an optional string format mask. Change the outer to_date into a to_char to return a string of the date in the format you want.

Answer (score 4):

Dates do not have a format - they are represented internally by [7- or 8- bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13568348/1509264). It is only when a client program is passed a date that that client program (potentially) gives it a format.

The default string format for dates in SQL/Plus or SQL Developer is set by the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter. Other clients will typically have parameters that you can set for the default date format (if they don't also use the `NLS` settings). However, beware that the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is a session parameter so it belongs to the user's session and multiple users can each have a different value for the parameter corresponding to how they have set it.

If you want to give a date a specific format then you will need to convert it to a string:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( DATE '2016-05-01', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS' )
FROM   DUAL;
```

**Why your query does not work**:

`TO_DATE( value, frmt )` expects a string value and a format mask. The inner `TO_DATE('2016-05-01 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')` is perfectly valid and will return the `DATE '2016-05-01'`.

However, the outer `TO_DATE()` is then being passed the `DATE` type you have just generated and the string format (instead of the two strings it is expecting). Oracle will implicitly call `TO_CHAR()` on the date and use the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter as the format mask. This is generating a string from the date and, given the error, the value of `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is not `MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS` so when the outer `TO_DATE()` tries to parse the implicitly created string it fails as the first number it reads is invalid for a month.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Use to_char

```
select to_char(to_date('2016-05-01 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD 
HH24:MI:SS'),'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual
```