# A non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

Tags: sql, oracle

when trying to add new rows I get "A non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected", should I change one of data types?
Data types in "tables"

```
CREATE TABLE TITLES
(
TITLE_ID                       VARCHAR2(6) NOT NULL,
TITLE                          VARCHAR2(80) NOT NULL,
CATEGORY                       CHAR(12) NOT NULL, 
PUB_ID                         NUMBER(4) NULL, 
PRICE                          INTEGER NULL,
ADVANCE                        INTEGER NULL,
TOTAL_SALES                    INTEGER NULL,
NOTES                          VARCHAR2(200) NULL, 
PUBDATE                        DATE NOT NULL,
CONTRACT                       INTEGER NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (TITLE_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (PUB_ID) REFERENCES PUBLISHERS(PUB_ID)
);
```

Query:

```
INSERT INTO TITLES (TITLE_ID,TITLE,CATEGORY,PUB_ID,PRICE,ADVANCE,TOTAL_SALES,NOTES,PUBDATE,CONTRACT) VALUES ('PC8888','Secrets of Silicon Valley','popular_comp',1389,20,8000,4095,'Muckraking reporting by two courageous women on the worlds largest computer hardware and software manufacturers.','12-JUN-87',1);
```

Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
01858. 00000 -  "a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected"
*Cause:    The input data to be converted using a date format model was
           incorrect.  The input data did not contain a number where a number was
           required by the format model.
*Action:   Fix the input data or the date format model to make sure the
           elements match in number and type.  Then retry the operation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`'12-JUN-87'` is not a date it is a string literal.

If you want to generate a date to insert into a table then you need to either:

- Use an [ANSI date literal](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51062): `DATE '1987-06-12'`
- Or, explicitly, convert a [string literal to a date](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm): `TO_DATE( '12-JUN-87', 'DD-MON-YY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American' )`

If you try to use a string literal as a date then [Oracle will try to implicitly convert it to a date](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38119778/1509264) using the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter as the format mask. If this format mask does not match the format of the string then an exception will be generated.

*Note: that the session parameters can be changed by the user and can be different for each user so you should not rely on this default value.*

Answer (score 2):

To insert a date/time value into the Oracle table, you'll need to use the `TO_DATE` function. The `TO_DATE` function allows you to define the format of the date/time value.

For example, we could insert the `'3-may-03 21:02:44'` value as follows:

```
insert into table_name
(date_field)
values
(TO_DATE('2003/05/03 21:02:44', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'));
```

In your case apply it to `'12-JUN-87'` using right date pattern. You can find more infrormation about date formats [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I was using Fedora 25, and oracle. I got the above error. I realized my data had no issue. I changed my system date settings from DENMARK to UNITED STATES and things are working fine. Maybe this can help a brother in need :-D

Comment: And my issue was not DATE related but with another bind cmd. So this was a red herring for me.