# In Oracle Database, TO_CHAR(Date) gives the result '00-000-00'

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a date column which I need to convert to character. But doing so it retrieves '00-000-00' even though the actual data has date value. Also, when I convert it again to date it gives the next day value.

For example:

```
Value: 25-MAR-17 (Date Datatype)
TO_CHAR(Value, 'DD-MON-YY'): '00-000-00'
TO_DATE(Value, 'DD-MON-YY'): '26-MAR-17'
```

And it's not happening for all the values but only the recent values.

Here is the Dump value present in that date column:

```
select OrderNumber, LoanDate, Dump(LoanDate) from OrderDetail
where OrderNumber=283402
```

```
OrderNumber| LoanDate  | Dump(LoanDate)
283402     | 26-MAR-17 | Typ=12 Len=7: 120,117,3,27,0,15,40
```

Can you please explain me why these weird things happening and how to handle this?

Comment: It's pretty hard for us to understand your question, because there is no way this should happen with the data you've presented. Please provide a reproducible test case. That is, a dummy table with sample data and the queries you're running which exhibit this behaviour. Cut down down the details to the essentials. You may find this exercise gives you insight and allows you to solve your problem without our help.

Comment: Date to Date conversion is just to check how it behaves.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] with the DDL and DML statements necessary to replicate the problem. Please also try `SELECT DUMP( your_date_column ) FROM your_table` and post what the value is.

Comment: You've edited your question but added no new substantial information. If you want a proper answer you're going to have to post some data which allows us to reproduce and investigate your issue.

Comment: What do you get from `DUMP(value)`?

Comment: select OrderNumber, LoanDate, Dump(LoanDate) from OrderDetail where OrderNumber=283402

OrderNumber|LoanDate|Dump(LoanDate)

283402|26-MAR-17|Typ=12 Len=7: 120,117,3,27,0,15,40

Comment: I've been trying to insert a date value that comes up with that dump without success. `create table t (d date); insert into t values (to_date('26/03/2017 23:59:59','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')); insert into t values (to_date('27/03/2017 00:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));select dump(d) from t;` returns `Typ=12 Len=7: 120,117,3,27,1,1,1 and Typ=12 Len=7: 120,117,3,26,24,60,60`. I suspect your data might have been corrupted, which might cause the behaviour you're seeing.

Comment: I think a zero (0) in that byte is invalid for an Oracle date, as Oracle stores the hour+1 there.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568193/how-are-dates-stored-in-oracle.

Answer (score 0):

*Putting as answer instead of comment, as it would be too big for comment*

What you are saying about `0` is not possible. You might get zeroes, if you have set NLS_DATE_FORMAT to display only time. Also you might get next date due to `timezone` conversion.

To troubleshoot it follow these steps, edit the question, and give the output in the question.

1. SELECT * FROM nls_session_parameters;
2. Run `select sysdate from dual;` and show the output.
3. Run this `alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';`
4. Run `select sysdate from dual` and show the output.
5. Now select your date again, `select <date column> from <your table> where rownum<2;`
6. Run `select to_char(date_column,'DD-MON-YYYY') from your_table where row_num<2;`

Comment: `nls_date_format` is not relevant when calling `to_char()`