# Oracle date and time datatype

Tags: oracle, date

I tried creating a table and one of the attributes 'appdate' must have a data dtype date which includes the time as well. I've tried using the to char but then it says invalid relational operator. HOw do i do this?

```
SQL> create table appointment
2  (StaffID char(10), constraint appointment_staffid_fk
  3  foreign key (staffid) references staff (staffid),
  4  PatientNum varchar2(10), constraint appointment_PatientNum_fk
  5  foreign key (patientnum) references patient (patientnum),
  6  appdate date
  7  constraint appointment_appdate_ch check (to_char(appdate, "mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss"))
  8  );
constraint appointment_appdate_ch check (to_char(appdate, "mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss"))
                                                                                  *
ERROR at line 7:
ORA-00920: invalid relational operator
```

Comment: You don't need add a constrain to date.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Could you please edit it to include some valid dates and some invalid dates, and explain why the invalid ones are invalid?

Comment: once you declare your column a 'DATE' the database ensures it's stored that way, and as the answer below says, DATEs by default have a TIME component in Oracle - even if you don't see it when querying it, it's there.

Comment: Are you perhaps trying to check that the time has been set to something other than midnight?

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle a `DATE` data type always has a time component so the check constraint is unnecessary.

It is stored internally as [7- or 8- bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13568348/1509264):

```
BYTE STORES
---- --------------------------
1    TRUNC( Year / 100 ) + 100
2    MOD( Year, 100 ) + 100
3    Month
4    Day
5    Hour + 1
6    Minute + 1
7    Seconds + 1
```

Even if you do not set a time component, it is still stored in the database has having the time `00:00:00` (so the last 3 bytes would be each set to 1).