# Oracle select date without time and keep date as data type

Tags: oracle, date, time

I have a column name `'Cos_Date'` with value like 14APR2017:00:00:00.

However, for a new column name `'Arrival_Date'`, I would like to keep the date information but omit time, and keep the data type as `Date` but not `Character`. Ex, 14APR2017.

I have tried:

```
  select TO_CHAR(Cos_Date, 'DD-MON-YYYY') ARRIVAL_DATE
```

But it will delete time information, but data type turns to `Character`.

I search on this site, and tried both:

```
  select TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(Cos_Date, 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'DD-MON-YYYY')  ARRIVAL_DATE
```

and:

```
  select TRUNC(Cos_Date) ARRIVAL_DATE
```

But it will not omit time information.

Can I try something else?

Thank you!

Comment: In Oracle there is no "pure" date data type. The date data type ALWAYS contains a time component. The best you can do is to have dates where the time component is 00:00:00. Why does that bother you? There is no problem created by this "limitation" of Oracle. (There **are** problems created by the lack of a "pure" **time** data type, with no date attached to it, but that's unrelated to your question.)

Comment: Oh, I see. Since I am using SAS to call Oracle and will let this table join another SAS table which contains data type is 'Date'. This bothers me. Maybe I can do one more data / proc sql step. Thanks @mathguy

Comment: I don't know how SAS works with Oracle, but if it works at all, and if SAS has "pure" date data type, I assume it is converted to date with the time set to 00:00:00 in Oracle. If you have two SAS tables with such date columns, you can simply join them in Oracle, the time portion being 00:00:00 on all dates will cause no problems in your join.

Comment: @mathguy  Right, I will take a look and that's doable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oracle there is no date data type that has only a year-month-day component.

The `DATE` data type is stored internally as [7- or 8-bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13568193/1509264) which always has year (2-bytes), month (1-byte), day (1-byte), hour (1-byte), minute (1-byte) and second (1-byte).

The `TIMESTAMP` data type also has fractional seconds (and can also have a time zone).

> Can I try something else?

No, you either use a `VARCHAR2` string or use a `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` and accept that it has a time component.

Answer (score 1):

You can't "omit" the time portion of a DATE column in Oracle. The DATE data type always contains a time component.  If you don't want to see the time, don't display it, e.g.,

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(Cos_Date),'DD-MON-YYYY') FROM dual;
```

Comment: Okay I see.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Selecting date values without time:

```
SELECT date_col
  FROM table
 WHERE TO_CHAR (date_col, 'HH24:MI:SS') = '00:00:00';
```