# How to search by to_date function?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table as below:

Table `Temp`:

```
ID  MAX MIN DATE_C  
1   34  24  21-APR-17 02.41.38.520000 PM    
2   32  26  20-APR-17 02.42.44.569000 PM
```

I execute the below SQL query to get temperature details on respective date:

```
SELECT *
FROM Temp t
WHERE t.date_c = TO_DATE( '2017-04-21', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
order by t.id
```

But it's returning empty records. Whats wrong with my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the time component on the column.  Here is one way:

```
SELECT *
FROM Temp t
WHERE TRUNC(t.date_c) = DATE '2017-04-21'
ORDER BY t.id;
```

However, I usually recommend using inequalities, rather than a function on the column:

```
SELECT *
FROM Temp t
WHERE t.date_c >= DATE '2017-04-21' AND
      t.date_c < DATE '2017-04-22'
ORDER BY t.id;
```

This allows the query to use an index on `date_c`.  I should add that the original version can use an index on `(trunc(date_c, id)`.

Comment: Does DATE keyword automatically detect date format..?

Comment: @SAPDEV . . . The `DATE` keyword allows ANSI standard formats (it is actually an ANSI standard keyword).  I only use YYYY-MM-DD formats, so I've never tried it with a different format.

Comment: `DATE` literal accepts **only** ANSI format: *The ANSI date literal contains no time portion, and must be specified in exactly this format ('YYYY-MM-DD').* from [Datetime Literals](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#BABGIGCJ)

Answer (score 0):

`21-APR-17 02.41.38.520000 PM` is not a `DATE`; it has a fractional seconds component so it is a `TIMESTAMP`.

So, if you want to find items that are on a particular day (inputting the `TIMESTAMP` using an [ISO/ANSI timestamp literal](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#sthref367)):

```
SELECT *
FROM   Temp
WHERE  date_c >= TIMESTAMP '2017-04-21 00:00:00' AND
       date_c <  TIMESTAMP '2017-04-21 00:00:00' + INTERVAL '1' DAY;
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM   Temp
WHERE  date_c >= TO_TIMESTAMP( :your_date_string, 'YYYY-MM-DD' ) AND
       date_c <  TO_TIMESTAMP( :your_date_string, 'YYYY-MM-DD' ) + INTERVAL '1' DAY;
```

> it's returning empty records. Whats wrong with my query?

`date_c = TO_DATE( '2017-04-21', 'YYYY-MM-DD')` matches all rows where the `date_c` value is exactly `2017-04-21 00:00:00.000000` (including the time component); if you do not have any rows with exactly that date **and** time then, as you noticed, it will return nothing. If you want to get records matching that day then you need to get values within a range of times between the start and end of the day.

Answer (score -3):

You need to pass date on the column.  Here is a way...

```
SELECT *
FROM Temp t
WHERE CAST(t.CREATED_ON as date)= N'2017-04-22'
ORDER BY t.id
```

Comment: Using `CAST( date_c AS DATE )` will not remove the time component as, in Oracle, there is no `DATETIME` data type and a `DATE` is stored internally as [7-bytes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568193/how-are-dates-stored-in-oracle) containing year (2-bytes) and month, day, hour, minute and second (1-byte each). All this will do is remove the fractional seconds from the `TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: Also, using the comparison of a `DATE` to a `NVARCHAR2` string will result in an implicit call to `TO_DATE` on the string using the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter. If this does not match the format of the string then the query will throw an exception. Given the OP's `TIMESTAMP` format appears to be `21-APR-17 02.41.38.520000 PM` then it is likely that the `DATE` format is similar and this will fail.