# Time format from 11:00:00 AM to 11:00:00 in Oracle

Tags: oracle

In the Table REC_ALL_TRADES I have the column as CALCTM which have the value like 11:00:00 AM and other also with out am.
I want to remove the AM from the value. Can you please let me know how to do this?

Comment: What is the data type of the `CALCTM` column?

Answer (score 0):

If the data type of the `CALCTM` column is a `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` then the data does not have a format.  Oracle stores `DATE` data types as [7-bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13568348/1509264) (and similar for `TIMESTAMP` data types) and it is not until it is passed to a client program (i.e. SQL/Plus, SQL Developer, Toad, Java, Python, etc) and that client program formats it according to whatever rules it has that the date gets a format.

You can give `DATE` and `TIMESTAMP` columns a format using `TO_CHAR( datevalue, format_model, [nls_settings] )` like this:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( CALCTM, 'HH24:MI:SS' )
FROM   REC_ALL_TRADES
```

If it is stored as a string then convert it to a `DATE` and then back to a string:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         TO_DATE( CALCTM, 'HH12:MI:SS AM' ),
         'HH24:MI:SS'
       )
FROM   REC_ALL_TRADES
```

If you have mixed valid/invalid formatted strings then use a `CASE` statement to differentiate:

```
SELECT CASE
       WHEN SUBSTR( TRIM( UPPER( CALCTM ) ), -1 ) IN ( 'AM', 'PM' )
       THEN TO_CHAR(
              TO_DATE( CALCTM, 'HH12:MI:SS AM' ),
              'HH24:MI:SS'
            )
       ELSE CALCTM
       END
FROM   REC_ALL_TRADES
```