# Converting ISO Date VARCHAR into DATE YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS in oracle

Tags: oracle, date, oracle11g

I have ISO Date format in oracle VARCHAR column in TABLE1, i have to insert this value into TABLE2 where i have column datatype as DATE.

**For Eg 1:**

- VARCHAR String Date1 - 2018-03-23T00:00:00.000+00:00
- I want to convert into date datatype as  - MM-DD-YYYY

While using below query getting the error,

```
INSERT INTO DATE_TEMP (DATE_VALUE) VALUES  (TO_DATE('2018-03-23T00:00:00.000+00:00','DD-MM-YYYY'));
```

**Error Code:**

```
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
```

**For Eg 2:**
 - VARCHAR String Dat2 - 2018-03-23T12:34:56.123+00:00

```
INSERT INTO DATE_TEMP (DATE_VALUE) VALUES TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2018-03-23T12:34:56.123+00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss.ff3TZH:TZM');
```

**Error Code:**

```
ORA-03001: unimplemented feature
```

Comment: You are missing the parentheses around the values. It should be `values ( to_timestamp_tz ... )` not `values to_timestamp_tz ....`

Comment: Thanks :) it works

Answer (score 3):

If everything behind the date is "0" (no hours, minutes, ..., as your example suggests), then it is fairly simple:

```
insert into table2 (date_column)
select to_date(substr(date_column, 1, 10), 'yyyy-mm-dd')
  from table1
```

Comment: Thanks for the query, what if I have in following format 2018-03-23T15:16:09.132+00:00

Comment: You'd use TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ, as a_horse showed in his answer.

Comment: When i execute this query it shows following error "ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0"

Comment: If the value is `2018-01-01T00:00:00+08:00` then this will ignore the time zone and insert the date as `2018-01-01` when, if you convert all the times to a consistent time zone, in UTC the time is actually `2017-12-31T16:00:00Z`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ( date_string, format_model )` to convert it to a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE` data type then you can use `AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'` to convert all values to a common time zone (since you are using a `DATE` column and this does not store time zone information) and either use `CAST( previous_value AS DATE )` to convert it explicitly to a `DATE` data type or allow Oracle to perform an implicit cast in the `INSERT` statement:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b496e8/4)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE date_temp ( date_value DATE );
```

**Query 1**:

```
INSERT INTO DATE_TEMP (
  DATE_VALUE
) VALUES(
  TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(
    '2018-03-23T00:00:00.000+00:00',
    'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3TZH:TZM'
  ) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
)

INSERT INTO DATE_TEMP (
  DATE_VALUE
) VALUES(
  TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(
    '2018-03-23T12:34:56.123+01:00',     -- Note: Different time zone
    'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3TZH:TZM'
  ) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
)

SELECT * FROM DATE_TEMP
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b496e8/4/2)**:

```
|           DATE_VALUE |
|----------------------|
| 2018-03-23T00:00:00Z |
| 2018-03-23T11:34:56Z | -- Note: value has been converted to the UTC time zone
```

As an aside:

> I want to convert into date datatype as - MM-DD-YYYY

A date does not have a format - it is [stored internally to the database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13568348/1509264) as 7-bytes (representing year, month, day, hour, minute and second) and it is not until whatever user interface you are using (i.e. SQL/Plus, SQL Developer, Java, etc) tries to display it to you, the user, and converts it into something you would find meaningful (usually a string) that the date has a format.

If you just want it as a date and do not want a time component then you can either use the `TRUNC( date_value )` function to truncate your value back to midnight.

**Update**

> Is it possible to insert record from table 1 to table 2. By this way we don't want to pass the value manually.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4063bb/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE date_temp ( date_value DATE );

CREATE TABLE string_temp ( string_value VARCHAR2(50) );

INSERT INTO string_temp
SELECT '2018-03-23T00:00:00.000+00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2018-03-23T12:34:56.123+01:00' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
INSERT INTO DATE_TEMP ( DATE_VALUE )
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(
         string_value,
         'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3TZH:TZM'
       ) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
FROM   string_temp


SELECT * FROM DATE_TEMP
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4063bb/1/1)**:

```
|           DATE_VALUE |
|----------------------|
| 2018-03-23T00:00:00Z |
| 2018-03-23T11:34:56Z |
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Is it possible to insert record from table 1 to table 2. By this way we don't want to pass the value manually. Actually it has lakhs of records and impossible to pass hard coded date parameter to insert query.

Answer (score 2):

Your string contains a time zone information, so you need to use `to_timestamp_tz`, not `to_date`

```
to_timestamp_tz('2018-03-23T00:00:00.000+00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss.ff3TZH:TZM')
```

That can be cast to a date if necessary.

Online example: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=021438eeec836b441b7f23ca57ff5af4

Comment: `INSERT INTO DATE_TEMP VALUES( TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ( '2018-03-22T12:34:56.123+01:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3TZH:TZM' ) );` would be implicitly cast to a date with a time at 12pm and ignore that the time zone is +01:00. Since the time zone is going to be lost, it would be better to change the time zone to one consistent zone before the cast to a date.