# Date Conversion in Oracle (YYYYMMDD format back to YYYYMMDD)

Tags: oracle, plsql

Hi I am pretty much new to Oracle and need an idea on how to do it.

Consideer I have a Text file and the value in the file is

'20180924' 
'20180923'

I read these value from the Pro*c and then I add 29 days to it, so the value now changes from 20180924 to 20180953. I don't want that to happen i want the value to be added as

```
 TO_DATE('20180924','yyyymmdd')+29 which returns the value as "23-OCT-18"
```

The answer is correct but i want the result to also be in the same **YYYYMMDD** format like **20181023.**

How do i achieve this ?

Comment: Hopefully you are going to use `yyyymmdd` format just to display the output and not to store it as a string in table.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just format it back.

```
to_char(TO_DATE('20180924','yyyymmdd')+29, 'yyyymmdd')
```

Comment: what if I want to end up with a date column and not char?

Comment: @mLstudent33, it was already a date. The question was how to change the display format of that date.

Answer (score 4):

Dates do not have a format - they are [represented internally by 7 or 8 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13568348/1509264).

If you want a date to have a format then you will need to convert it to a data type that can be formatted - i.e. a string:

```
TO_CHAR( TO_DATE( '20180924', 'yyyymmdd' ) + 29, 'YYYYMMDD' )
```

When SQL/Plus (or SQL Developer) displays date data types they implicitly convert them to strings (since this is more meaningful to you, the user, than displaying the raw bytes) and uses the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter as the format model in this implicit conversion. If you want to change this then you can use:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYYMMDD';
```

and then your query:

```
TO_DATE( '20180924', 'yyyymmdd' ) + 29
```

should (provided your SQL client uses this setting and does not have their own internal format preferences) give the output you expect. *(Note: this will change the default format for the client to display all dates in this session and not just this one statement.)*

Answer (score -2):

select TO_NUMBER((TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(HIREDATE,'DD-MON-YY'),'YYYYMMDD')) FROM EMP;

select TO_NUMBER((TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(HIREDATE,'DD-MON-YY'),'YYYYMMDD'))FROM EMP

---

20201101

select TO_NUMBER((TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(SYSDATE,'DD-MON-YY'),'YYYYMMDD')) FROM DUAL;