# Converting TIMESTAMP column in 12 HR format into Date column with 24 HR format

Tags: sql, oracle

In a table, I have a TIMESTAMP column in 12 HR format which I want to convert into Date column with 24 HR format.

```
Insert_Date

3-JAN-19 09.50.25.000000 AM 

23-JAN-19 08.54.37.000000 PM
```

I tried following-

```
to_char(Insert_Date,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS')
```

Expected Result is -

```
3-JAN-19 09.50.25

23-JAN-19 20.54.37
```

Answer (score 2):

Dates (and timestamps) do not have a format - they are [represented internally by 7 or 8 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13568348/1509264) for a date or 20 bytes for a timestamp. The only time they are formatted is either when the user interface you are using implicitly converts then so it can display something meaningful to the user (i.e. when displaying a `SELECT` statement) or when the user explicitly converts it using `TO_CHAR`.

Given this, you do not need to change any format; just `CAST` to a different data type:

```
SELECT CAST( your_timestamp_column AS DATE ) FROM your_table
```

---

Why does it display `TIMESTAMP`s using 12 hour clock and `DATE`s using 24 hour clock?

Because that's what your user interface has its defaults set to.

For SQL/Plus & SQL Developer the defaults are in the user's NLS session parameters:

```
SELECT parameter, value
FROM   NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS
WHERE  parameter IN ( 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT', 'NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT' );
```

You should see something like:

```
PARAMETER            VALUE
-------------------- ---------------------------
NLS_DATE_FORMAT      DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT DD-MON-RR HH12:MI:SS.FF6 AM
```

You can alter them using:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF9';
```

If, for example, you wanted them both in ISO8601 format.

Answer (score 0):

```
CAST(timestamp_expression AS DATE);
```

e.g. `SELECT CAST(SYSTIMESTAMP AS DATE) FROM dual;`

For presentation:

```
to_char(Insert_Date,'DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS')
```