# Have error ORA-01861 when I want to change it to "date column type"

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I have a table which calculates some measure base on the Date column type.
also, that should be store date as Persian calendar but at the end when I using TO_DATE function for changing its type have an ORA-01861 error on 19,20,21 days of the May while there is such date is already exist and the second month of Persian calendar has 31 days.
here is my query:

```
with a as
 (select to_char(to_date('20190518', 'YYYYMMDD'),
                 'YYYYMMDD',
                 'NLS_CALENDAR=PERSIAN') PERSIAN_DATE
    from DUAL
  UNION ALL
  select to_char(to_date('20190519', 'YYYYMMDD'),
                 'YYYYMMDD',
                 'NLS_CALENDAR=PERSIAN') PERSIAN_DATE
    from DUAL
  UNION ALL
  select to_char(to_date('20190520', 'YYYYMMDD'),
                 'YYYYMMDD',
                 'NLS_CALENDAR=PERSIAN') PERSIAN_DATE
    from DUAL
  UNION ALL
  select to_char(to_date('20190521', 'YYYYMMDD'),
                 'YYYYMMDD',
                 'NLS_CALENDAR=PERSIAN') PERSIAN_DATE
    from DUAL
  UNION ALL
  select to_char(to_date('20190522', 'YYYYMMDD'),
                 'YYYYMMDD',
                 'NLS_CALENDAR=PERSIAN') PERSIAN_DATE
    from DUAL)
SELECT TO_DATE(PERSIAN_DATE, 'YYYY/MM/DD') pers_date FROM A
```

my oracle database version is Oracle 12.2.0.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You convert a sting to a DATE, then to a string and back again to a DATE, that's useless.

Try this one:

```
WITH a AS
 (SELECT TO_DATE('20190518', 'YYYYMMDD') PERSIAN_DATE
    FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_DATE('20190519', 'YYYYMMDD') PERSIAN_DATE
    FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_DATE('20190520', 'YYYYMMDD') PERSIAN_DATE
    FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_DATE('20190521', 'YYYYMMDD') PERSIAN_DATE
    FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_DATE('20190522', 'YYYYMMDD') PERSIAN_DATE
    FROM DUAL)
SELECT to_char(PERSIAN_DATE, 'YYYYMMDD', 'NLS_CALENDAR=PERSIAN') pers_date 
FROM A
```

or shorter:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('20190517', 'YYYYMMDD')+LEVEL, 'YYYYMMDD', 'NLS_CALENDAR=PERSIAN') pers_date 
FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5;
```

Or use `DATE` literals and NLS session values:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_CALENDAR = 'PERSIAN';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYYMMDD'; 

SELECT DATE '2019-05-17' + LEVEL pers_date 
FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5;
```

Comment: I try with TO_CHAR function and I know its working.but the problem happens when I should use TO_DATE function when to store it in a table with a column with "DATE" type.

Comment: can you store it as a Date type in a  table?

Comment: Yes, of course. A `DATE` is a DATE, no matter whether the **display** style is Gregorian or Persian

Comment: No, Its important for me, because in my business it's should calculate all measure base on Persian mode and these two calendars have different day, month and year at the same time .

Comment: No, in Oracle a DATE is stored with an internal format which is independent from the calendar. You need to set the calendar only for the display, not for storing or calculations. If you say `SYSDATE + 1` then it means tomorrow - in Gregorian as well as in Persian.

Comment: can you send reference or link about it that is just for display not for any store or calculation?

Comment: Check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568193/how-are-dates-stored-in-oracle

Comment: @GhostMan you should read this book https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/nlspg/datetime-data-types-and-time-zone-support.html#GUID-7A1BA319-767A-43CC-A579-4DAC7063B243

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit thank you, but I use the above query and its work in many days of the year and just had problem with less than ten days in the year...

Comment: What do you mean by "had problem with less than ten days in the year..."? Please specify the issue you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute your select just for the 18th (that you were not having an issue with) and adding the raw value you will see it is returning

```
with a as
     (select to_char(to_date('20190518', 'YYYYMMDD'),
                     'YYYYMMDD',
                     'NLS_CALENDAR=PERSIAN') PERSIAN_DATE
        from DUAL)
    SELECT PERSIAN_DATE, TO_DATE(PERSIAN_DATE, 'YYYY/MM/DD') pers_date FROM A;

Persian Date    pers_date
13980228        28/FEB/98  00:00:00
```

So oracle is trying discarding the first two characters and making the best date it can out of the rest (pretty sure this is not the correct Persian date).

So following the same logic when you run this for 19th (we can only get the raw value as to date will error)

```
with a as
  (select to_char(to_date('20190519', 'YYYYMMDD'),
                 'YYYYMMDD',
                 'NLS_CALENDAR=PERSIAN') PERSIAN_DATE
    from DUAL)
SELECT PERSIAN_DATE pers_date FROM A;

Persian Date
13980229
```

Following the same logic as above discard the first two characters and you get 29 Feb 1998... this is not a valid date.

As others have stated in the comments Oracle just stores the date it doesn't care about the calendar, you need to convert to the appropriate calendar for display.

For a good explanation of how oracle stores dates see

[How are dates stored in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568193/how-are-dates-stored-in-oracle)