# How to convert Timestamp to Date column in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a `TIMESTAMP(6)` column filled with data. Time information is not important anymore. How can I migrate this to the `DATE` column and save data?

What is the easiest way to do this in SQL?

Comment: Are you aware that a `DATE` column **still** has a time part?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name how comes?

Comment: @Mike In Oracle both [`DATE`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13568348/1509264) and `TIMESTAMP` always have year, month, day, hour, minute and second components. `TIMESTAMP` may have optional fractional seconds and/or time zone components. There is no `DATETIME` data type in Oracle. Just converting to a `DATE` is not going to get rid of the time component.

Comment: @Mike: because that's what Oracle decided over 40 years ago how a DATE column should look like

Comment: Looks like a `TIMESTAMP` internally takes 20 bytes and a `DATE` 8 bytes, so in theory you may save some space, but unless you have a lot of columns to change, you may not save much.  Also be careful that the application does *not* need timezone information as the `DATE` datatype cannot store time zone information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can do direct modify to this column and all will be ok:

```
ALTER TABLE testTable
MODIFY test_c date;
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=067137b1f7f453246ca9abd8a2bdcfc5)

Comment: @Andrew: the difference is, that this is more efficient as it doesn't create a new column as MT0's answer does.

Comment: @Andrew This answer modifies the column in place; so if the aim is just to cast to a simpler format discarding any fractional seconds then this will do it simply and efficiently. If there is a need to review the changes then you might need to create another column (i.e. if it was a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` column and you want to convert the data to a common time zone rather that just discard the fractional seconds and time zone) but that doesn't appear to be the case for the OP.

Comment: I just wanted to note, if this is the case: "Time information is not important anymore" that this is a valid option then...And when I check the description about the down vote it says: "This answer is not useful". Well I do not see why it is not...

Answer (score 2):

A `DATE` column always has year, month, day, hour, minute and second components so converting to a `DATE` is not going to eliminate those time components (but will discard the fractional seconds stored in the `TIMESTAMP`).

Add the new column:

```sql
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD new_date_column DATE;
```

Then use an implicit cast:

```sql
UPDATE table_name
SET new_date_column = old_timestamp_column;
```

Or an explicit cast:

```sql
UPDATE table_name
SET new_date_column = CAST( old_timestamp_column AS DATE );
```

Then you can review the changes and drop the old column.

If you want to set all the time components to zero then you can use `TRUNC`:

```sql
UPDATE table_name
SET new_date_column = TRUNC( old_timestamp_column );
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3b678dabc2ffb1c09e5a913853f7d75b)

If you just want to change the column's data type without reviewing the data then use [VBokšić's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58914703/1509264) or modify the column and then use `TRUNC` to zero the time components:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY column_name DATE;
UPDATE table_name SET column_name = TRUNC( column_name );
```