# What is the difference between these 2 sql queries?

Tags: sql, oracle, jpa, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
select * from accounts where sysdate - 100 < last_active_dt;

select * from accounts where sysdate - 100 <= last_active_dt;
```

Both of the queries returned the same result.

> I was thinking that for the first query, it **would not** select
>   records on the **day** of `last_active_dt`.  For the 2nd query, it
>   **will** select records on the day of `last_active_dt`.

But this does not seem to be the case as both returned the same results.

**Is there any difference to it? And how can I see the difference?**

```
last_active_dt column follows a date format DD-MON-YYYY
```

Comment: Do you have any data in the accounts table in which sysdate - 100 == last_active_dt?

Answer (score 2):

> `last_active_dt` column follows a date format `DD-MON-YYYY`

No, it doesn't (but it may look like it does in the user interface you are using).

A `DATE` data type always has year, month, day, hour, minute and second components and is stored (without any formatting) in [7 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568193/how-are-dates-stored-in-oracle). It is the user interface that applies a (default) format to the date and this may hide the time component from you.

You can use:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
```

To change the default date format used in SQL*Plus (and SQL Developer) to see the date with all the components.

Equally, `SYSDATE` is of a `DATE` data type and has year, month, day, hour, minute and second components so what you are probably intending is:

```sql
select * from accounts where TRUNC( sysdate ) - INTERVAL '100' DAY < last_active_dt;
```

This will get all the columns where the `last_active_dt` is after midnight of the day 100 days ago (even if it 1 second after). This will work if all your `last_active_dt` values have the times `TRUNC`ated to exactly midnight `00:00:00` but not if the column as non-zero time components as you will still get values with times from `00:00:01` to `23:59:59` of the day 100 days ago.

If your `last_active_dt` has a non-zero time component then you want:

```sql
select * from accounts where TRUNC( sysdate ) - INTERVAL '99' DAY <= last_active_dt;
```

Comment: As I go further into time, now this has all make sense with the current thing I am doing now. Thanks a lot!