# How to make a constraint on DATE FORMAT in ORACLE

Tags: oracle, date

say my usual Date format is '14-jan-2019' and i want my date to only be accepted as 'YYYY-MM-DD' how do i do that? and can i change jan to an actual number?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How are dates stored in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568193/how-are-dates-stored-in-oracle)

Comment: a date colum does not have a format, shouldn't be confused with a formatted date string.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, the right / correct way to do that is to declare your *date column* (or variable or whatever it is) as **DATE**, e.g.

```
create table test (date_column date);
```

or

```
declare
  l_date_variable date;
begin
  ...
```

Doing so, you'd let the database take care about valid values.

You'd then be able to enter data any way you want, using any valid date format mask, e.g.

```
to_date('06.01.2020', 'dd.mm.yyyy')
date '2020-01-06'
to_date('2020-06-01', 'yyyy-dd-mm')
```

etc. - all those values would be *valid*.

Answer (score 2):

A `DATE` data type has no format - it is stored internally as [7-bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13568348/1509264) representing year (2 bytes) and month, day, hour, minute and second (1 byte each).

`'14-JAN-2019'` is not a date - it is a text literal.

If you want to store date values then use a `DATE` data type.

If you want to only accept strings of a specific format as input then in whatever user interface you use to talk to the database then accept only that format. If you are converting strings to `DATE`s and wanting an exact format then you can use:

```
TO_DATE( '2019-01-14', 'fxYYYY-MM-DD' )
```

*Note: the `fx` format model will mean that the exact format is expected and the typical [string-to-date conversion rules](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#sthref478) will not be applied.*