# Getting date in oracle from timestamp without trailing o's?

Tags: oracle, date

I have been scouring stack and google to find a way to extract a date from timestamp w/o the trailing zero's still being a date and NOT a VARCHAR variable-

for example:

```
SELECT TRUNC(to_date('2012-07-18 13:27:18', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')) FROM DUAL
```

gives: `18-JUL-12 00:00:00`

I want it in `'18/07/2012'` date format in the end.

TIA in advance if this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have been scouring stack and google to find a way to extract a date from timestamp w/o the trailing zero's still being a date and NOT a `VARCHAR` variable

You cannot if you want the value to still be a `DATE`

A `DATE` is stored internally as [7-bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13568348/1509264) and always has year (2 bytes), month, day, hour, minute and second (1 byte each) components.

A `TIMESTAMP` is stored internally with 11-20 bytes with the same year-to-second components as a `DATE` but also fractional seconds components and optional time zone components.

Neither a `DATE` nor a `TIMESTAMP` has a format because they are just binary data and you cannot remove the time component because they both always have a time component.

> ```sql
> SELECT TRUNC(to_date('2012-07-18 13:27:18', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')) FROM DUAL
> ```
>
> gives: `18-JUL-12 00:00:00`

The query outputs a `DATE` and depending on the user interface that you use then the date may be implicitly cast to a string for outputting. SQL/Plus and SQL Developer use the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter to implicitly convert `DATE`s to strings when it is displaying it to the user:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
SELECT TRUNC(to_date('2012-07-18 13:27:18', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')) FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs: `2012-07-18 13:27:18`

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD';
SELECT TRUNC(to_date('2012-07-18 13:27:18', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')) FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs: `2012-07-18`

However, **ANY** user can change their own session parameters at **ANY** time so you should never rely on implicit formatting of dates.

If you want a `DATE` then you should not expect it to be formatted in any particular way as it is just binary data. If you want a formatted date then you should explicitly convert it to a string with the formatting you require using `TO_CHAR`:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         TRUNC( to_date('2012-07-18 13:27:18', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') ),
         'DD/MM/YYYY'
       )
FROM   DUAL;
```

Outputs: `18/07/2012`

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=11c2e6a5fa47587b0e4964acb1c6d44e)

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's what you say. In my database, it results in

```
SQL> SELECT TRUNC(to_date('2012-07-18 13:27:18', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')) FROM DUAL;

TRUNC(TO
--------
18.07.12

SQL>
```

If you want to get a different result, alter session:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_Date_format = 'dd/mm/yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> SELECT TRUNC(to_date('2012-07-18 13:27:18', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')) FROM DUAL;

TRUNC(TO_D
----------
18/07/2012
```

Or apply `TO_CHAR` with desired format mask:

```
SQL> SELECT to_char(TRUNC(to_date('2012-07-18 13:27:18', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')), 'dd/mm/yyyy') FROM DUAL;

TO_CHAR(TR
----------
18/07/2012
```

---

Although, I don't see much sense in what you are doing:

- first you convert a string ('2012-07-18 13:27:18') to date
- then you truncate time part of it
- finally, you want to get only date part, but as a string again

So, why don't you just use

```
SQL> select '18/07/2012' from dual;

'18/07/201
----------
18/07/2012
```

(Of course, unless that *date string* actually comes somewhere from a table which is wrong; never store dates into `VARCHAR2` columns).

Comment: I am just using  the '2012-07-18 13:27:18'  as an example. The actual data is a timestamp field.

Comment: What do you call a "timestamp field"? Tables have *columns*, not *fields*. "Field" is a term used in e.g. Oracle Forms; nowadays these are "items". Or is it a timestamp datatype? Could you express yourself more precise? It would be easier to discuss, then.

Comment: The column itself  has a datetime value.

Answer (score 0):

The data types DATE and TIMESTAMP are an oracle internal, binary type.  *BY DEFINITION* they contain a time component - DATE resolved down to the seconds, TIMESTAMP down to the nano-second.  Conversely, since these are internal, binary structures, what you see on your screen is, again *BY DEFINITION*, converted to a character string - VARCHAR2.  You may not have specified the TO_CHAR, but the very act of selecting a DATE or TIMESTAMP to be displayed (not used internally) *forced* oracle to apply a TO_CHAR to it.

Since these data types inherently, by defintion, contain time components, it is logically inconsistent to say that you want to "extract a date from timestamp w/o the trailing zero's (the time component) still being a date and NOT a VARCHAR variable-".