# Comparing Date field with specific datetime in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I have a table with a Date field `time_process` like `'1/11/2021 5:10:16 AM'`.

I want to select records has `time_process >= '1/11/2021 05:00:00 AM'`
But when I query:

```
select * from DATA_RUN where time_process >= '1/11/2021 05:00:00 AM'
```

Has error:

```
[1]: ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

How can I compare this Date field with specific datetime?

Answer (score 3):

You should use `to_date` to convert string to date as follows:

```
select * from DATA_RUN 
   where time_process >= To_date('01/11/2021 05:00:00 AM', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM')
```

Answer (score 2):

## Option 1 - Date and Interval literals:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   DATA_RUN
WHERE  time_process >= DATE '2021-01-11' + INTERVAL '05:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND
```

Or, since you don't have any minutes or seconds, then you could use:

```sql
WHERE  time_process >= DATE '2021-01-11' + INTERVAL '5' HOUR
```

## Option 2 - Timestamp literal:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   DATA_RUN
WHERE  time_process >= TIMESTAMP '2021-01-11 05:00:00'
```

## Option 3 - Convert string using `TO_DATE` function:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   DATA_RUN
WHERE  time_process >= TO_DATE( '1/11/2021 05:00:00 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM' )
```

---

As an aside,

> I have a table with a Date field `time_process` like `'1/11/2021 5:10:16 AM'`

A `DATE` column has no format as it is stored internally in a binary format consisting of [7-bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568193/how-are-dates-stored-in-oracle) (century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second). Formatting the value of a `DATE` is left up to the user interface; for SQL/Plus and SQL Developer (among others), this is determined by the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter but each user can set their own values in each of their sessions at any time so you cannot assume that there will be a consistent format to a `DATE` column.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a `DATE` datatype column, don't compare it to a string (because, this: `'1/11/2021 05:00:00 AM'` is a string, not a date).

So:

```
select * 
from data_run
where time_process >= to_date('11.01.2021 05:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss');
```