# Inserting date column in dataframe to Oracle table

Tags: python, oracle

I need to insert a pandas dataframe into an Oracle table. One of the columns is a date, but it looks like this:

```
09/07/2021 13:07
```

How could I convert it into a date type column so as Oracle takes it when inserting the value?

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    call_date          TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    cacont_acc         VARCHAR2(12) NOT NULL,
    status             VARCHAR2(5),
    exhausted          VARCHAR2(20),
    attempts           NUMBER,
    exhausted_reason   VARCHAR2(2000),
    agency             VARCHAR2(10)
);
```

EDIT: This is how the python process to insert the dataframe looks like:

```
# Insert the exhausted df into Oracle
truncate_exhausted = """
truncate table test
"""

insert_exhausted = """
INSERT INTO test (
    call_date,
    cacont_acc,
    status,
    exhausted,
    attempts,
    exhausted_reason,
    agency
) VALUES (
    :1,
    :2,
    :3,
    :4,
    :5,
    :6,
    :7
)
"""

rows = [tuple(x) for x in df_exhausted.values]

cur.execute(truncate_exhausted)
cur.executemany(insert_exhausted, rows)
conn.commit()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "but it looks like this"? Is this the output when you select the data or is this the input value you like to insert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure the date value in python is a [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) value, not a **string**.

In case it cannot be changed, this workaround should work:

```
insert_exhausted = """
INSERT INTO test (
    call_date,
    cacont_acc,
    status,
    exhausted,
    attempts,
    exhausted_reason,
    agency
) VALUES (
    TO_TIMESTAMP(:1, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi'),
    :2,
    :3,
    :4,
    :5,
    :6,
    :7
)
"""
```

**Update**

Make a clear distinction of your data.

- The **input value**: This is python value. So far, it is not clear to me whether this is a `datetime` data type value or a `string` representing a date, e.g. `09/07/2021 13:07` of format `dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi`
- The **stored value** of `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` data type in your database. This value does not have any format, it is stored as https://stackoverflow.com/a/13568348/3027266
- The (default) **displayed value**. This is controlled by `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` and `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` session parameters. Or you can explicitly define your own format with [TO_CHAR](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions216.htm#SQLRF06129) function.

Comment: Actually, by converting the python value to datetime, Oracle was able to take it. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I just realised that the date formats python vs Oracle do differ. For example, when passed 08/07/2021, Oracle takes 07/08/2021. How can I make Oracle take the exact date provided in the dataframe without changing it?

Comment: When the python datatype is a `datetime` value, then it should not matter. Elaborate when you say "Oracle takes 07/08/2021" - What is 07/08/2021? Please see my update, I have no idea which of these three values you are talking about. And please do not expect us to guess if this date means July, 8th or August 7th.

Answer (score 1):

That (09/07/2021 13:07) looks like a date (along with time) to me. What would you want to insert (if not that)? Is it, maybe, that you need to use `to_date('09/07/2021 13:07', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi')`?

---

Besides, if you modified the table so that date column has its **default** value, you wouldn't have to pass anything, e.g.

```
SQL> create table test
  2    (call_date   date           default sysdate,       --> this
  3     status      varchar2(5)
  4    );

Table created.

SQL> insert into test (status) values ('A');     --> no CALL_DATE column here

1 row created.

SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> select * from test;

CALL_DATE           STATU
------------------- -----
13.07.2021 14:13:22 A

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can't have the default date added, I need the one included in the pandas dataframe. I've edited my question to show the full process.

Comment: Aha. I don't know anything about the *pandas dataframe*, sorry.