# How to compare different format date in oracle?

Tags: oracle, date, datetime

i have a table that use date, and need to return row between certain date.

column name is tg_konfi and column format is DATE, and tg_konfi date is 02-FEB-21 like that.

i have try this

```
SELECT * From table where to_date(tg_konfi,'DD-MON-YY') between to_date('2021-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') and to_date('2021-10-07','YYYY-MM-DD');
```

and its return nothing. Am i missing something, or I do this wrong?

Comment: Is tg_konfi defined as a DATE column? If so you don’t need to use to_date.

Comment: yes, and its still not returning anything

Comment: There is no need to call `TO_DATE` on a value which is already a `DATE`. `02-FEB-21` is just the **default** display format according to `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `tg_confi` is a date datatype column, do not use the `to_date` on that column.

Use the following query:

```
SELECT * 
  From table 
 where tg_konfi between to_date('2021-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') 
                    and to_date('2021-10-07','YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Answer (score 0):

A date does not have a format - it is [stored internally to the database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13568348/1509264) as 7-bytes (representing century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second) and it is not until whatever user interface you are using (i.e. SQL/Plus, SQL Developer, Java, etc.) tries to display it to you, the user, that is is converted it into something you would find meaningful (usually a string) that the date has a format (and that conversion is done by the user interface and not by the database).

If your values are all `DATE` data types then this means that you do not need to worry about any format - because they won't have a format in the database.

The simplest method is to use date literals:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table
WHERE  tg_konfi BETWEEN DATE '2021-01-01'
                    AND DATE '2021-10-07';
```

or explicitly convert from a string literal using `TO_DATE`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table
WHERE  tg_konfi BETWEEN TO_DATE( '2021-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD' )
                    AND TO_DATE( '2021-10-07', 'YYYY-MM-DD' );
```

This will get all rows where `tg_konfi` is between `2021-01-01T00:00:00` and `2021-10-07T00:00:00`.

If you want the range to include up to `2021-10-07T23:59:59` then you can use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table
WHERE  tg_konfi >= DATE '2021-01-01'
AND    tg_konfi <  DATE '2021-10-07' + INTERVAL '1' DAY; -- or DATE '2021-10-08'
```