# how can we change one date format to another format in oracle sql? ORA-01861

Tags: oracle, date, plsql

How can we change the date format from `DD-MON-YYYY` to this format `YYYY-MM-DD`.

I have a date type column in a table. I want to display that value of that date column in this format - `YYYY-MM-DD`.

I tried with this -

```
disp_date := to_char(to_date(disp_date,'dd-mm-rrrr'),'rrrr-mm-dd')
```

and

```
disp_date := to_char(to_date(disp_date,'dd-mm-yyyy'),'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

While executing the above I got an error message stating that:

```
ORA-01861 Literal does not match format string
```

Please note the below details of my system,

```
select value from v$nls_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE';
--AMERICAN
select value from v$nls_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT';
--DD-MON-RRRR
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the **default** display format then run

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD';
select disp_date from ...
```

Note, your client application may change the format again according to settings in this client application.

Comment: If the client application is not SQL/Plus or SQL Developer (and maybe a limited handful of others) then this is not likely to affect how the client displays date data types as that is going to be controlled by a parameter on the client application and not a session parameter in the database.

Comment: I have assigned the converted value into another variable and now it is working fine.

Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 3):

If column's datatype is `DATE` - which is what your sentence suggests:

> I have a date type column in a table

then you don't `to_date` it - it already *is* a date. Just apply `to_char` with desired format mask, e.g.

```
select to_char(disp_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd') from your_table
```

Comment: Actually I tried that too, but it is not working while assigning it to the same variable again (after to_char conversion), 
So I declared a new variable and assigned the converted value to that, now it is working fine.

Thank you so much for your response.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you made it work.

Answer (score 0):

A date does not have a format - it is [stored internally to the database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13568348/1509264) as a binary value using 7-bytes (representing century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second). It is not until whatever user interface you are using (i.e. SQL/Plus, SQL Developer, Java, etc.) tries to display it to you, the user, that is is converted it into something you would find meaningful (usually a string) that the date is formatted (and that conversion is done by the user interface and not by the database).

> How can we change one date format to another format in oracle?

Since a date does not have a format then this question does not make sense.

If instead, you ask:

> How can we display a date in a format in oracle?

If you want to **display** the date with a specific format then you want to explicitly convert it from a date to a string using `TO_CHAR` (rather than relying on an implicit conversion by the user interface). Since it is already a `DATE` then you do not need to use `TO_DATE` on it and can just use:

```sql
DECLARE
  date_value     DATE := SYSDATE;
  formatted_date VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
  formatted_date := TO_CHAR(date_value, 'yyyy-mm-dd');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( formatted_date );
END;
/
```

---

Now, if your `disp_date` variable is a string (and not a date) then your code works:

```sql
DECLARE
  disp_date VARCHAR2(11) := TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-RRRR');
BEGIN
  disp_date := TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(disp_date, 'DD-MON-RRRR'), 'yyyy-mm-dd');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( disp_date );
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4b7a94b159a90bbd129277c902f21085)*

Comment: Thank you so much for your in depth explanation and answer. 
Yes, Actually later I tried to assign the converted value into another string type variable and it is working fine.

Thanks a lot!