# Oracle Format Date without Converting it to CHAR

Tags: sql, oracle, formatting, to-date, fusion

I Want to Format Date in Oracle without Converting to char e.g. `to_char(date,'dd/mm/yyyy'`), I tried using  `to_date`:

```
to_date(papf.start_date,'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

But it doesn't really format anything, in addition I want the format to be `mm/dd/yyyy`, how can I do that?

Comment: to_date is one way. but if you want the data to come in as mm/dd/yyyy then you will have to convert it to_char its not possible without it.

Comment: Why do you use `to_date` when you want `to_char`?

Comment: Dates have an internal 7-byte representation, they don't have any intrinsic format. You format them for display, as a string, either implicitly or explicitly; or your client does that for you, usually using your NLS settings. What are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: you need to show papf.start_date data type.  Please tell me you are not storing a date as a VARCHAR2.

Comment: no its a date, i just want to format it without converting it to char, anyway, a solution i have that is easier is to format the date on the ```rtf``` template itself, it worked

Answer (score 3):

A `DATE` is a binary data type consisting of [7 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568193) representing century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second. It **ALWAYS** has those 7 components and it is **NEVER** stored in any particular human-readable format.

Asking:

> I Want to Format Date in Oracle without Converting to char

Does not make sense given that a date is stored as binary data. It is like asking to look at the bytes of an MP3 file without converting it to sound or to look at a JPEG file without decoding the bytes to pixels and colours.

If you want to have a date in a particular format then you need to convert it to a non-binary format and that would be a string of characters.

You can either:

1. Explicitly convert a date to a string using `TO_CHAR`:

   ```sql
   SELECT TO_CHAR(papf.start_date,'yyyy-mm-dd')
   FROM   your_table papf
   ```
2. Allow whatever client application you are using to access the database to implicitly format the date as a string when it displays it to you. If you are using SQL*Plus or SQL Developer then they will use the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter as the default format model for implicitly converting between dates and strings and you can set that using:

   ```sql
   ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'yyyy-mm-dd';
   ```

   Then select the value as a date and allow the client to format it:

   ```sql
   SELECT papf.start_date
   FROM   your_table papf
   ```

   If you are using a different client application then you will need to look at its documentation and find out how it formats dates.
3. If you really don't want it as a string then you can use:

   ```sql
   SELECT TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(papf.start_date, 'DDMMYYYY'))
   FROM   your_table papf
   ```

   or

   ```sql
   SELECT 1000000 * EXTRACT(DAY   FROM papf.start_date)
          + 10000 * EXTRACT(MONTH FROM papf.start_date)
          +     1 * EXTRACT(YEAR  FROM papf.start_date)
   FROM   your_table papf
   ```

   Which both display it as an 8-digit number (but won't be in your desired format with the slashes).

---

> I tried using to_date:
>
> ```sql
> to_date(papf.start_date,'yyyy-mm-dd')
> ```
>
> But it doesn't really format anything

It doesn't format anything because a `DATE` is a binary data-type and never stores any particular (human-readable) format.

Additionally, it can cause issues with the date as `TO_DATE` takes a string as the first argument so you are effectively performing an implicit date-to-string conversion and then converting it back to a date so the query is effectively the same as:

```sql
to_date(
  TO_CHAR(
    papf.start_date,
    (SELECT value FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS WHERE parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT')
  ),
  'yyyy-mm-dd'
)
```

So, if you do:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MM-RR';

SELECT TO_CHAR(
          SYSDATE,
          'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'
       ) AS today,
       TO_CHAR(
          to_date(SYSDATE,'yyyy-mm-dd'),
          'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'
       ) AS today_with_to_date
FROM   DUAL;
```

Then it outputs:

| TODAY | TODAY_WITH_TO_DATE |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-03-20 18:42:40 | 0020-03-23 00:00:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fpnax36H)

In this case, using `TO_DATE` has swapped the year and day over and has truncated the time back to midnight.

**NEVER** use `TO_DATE` on a value that is already a date.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to specify a literal date format (which is in fact recommended practice), you can set the default for all date-to-string conversions:

```
alter session set nls_date_format='mm/dd/yyyy';

select start_date from ...
```

However, while this will work in sqlplus and any other client that converts everything to a string, should your client be actually wanting a date, no conversion will take place, and you wouldn't want it to. Work with dates as actual dates, not strings, until you get to the final point of displaying it to a human or on a report. If you are using a database browsing or reporting tool of some kind, it is likely that it has an Options section somewhere where you can set the default NLS date format automatically.