# How to Insert DATE value alone in TIMESTAMP datatype in Oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I am trying to insert Date value into Timestamp datatype in Oracle table.

I am expecting the output as "31/08/2023". But somehow i am not able to succeed. The value is always inserted as "31-AUG-23 12.00.00.000000000 AM" irrespective of which format i use,such as, TO_DATE, DATE, trunc, etc.

Below is the sample code i am trying to INSERT.

```
Insert into ABC.TABLE1 (SYSTEM,NAME,EMPID,CONNECTIONID,LOGDATE,DEPT) values ('B11','PATRICK','G18','B11A1',TO_DATE('31/08/2023','DD/MM/YYYY'),'ING');
```

The output is always stored as "31-AUG-23 12.00.00.000000000 AM".

I tried below formats.

```
TO_DATE('31/08/2023','DD/MM/YYYY')
trunc('31/08/2023','DD/MM/YYYY')
DATE('31/08/2023','DD/MM/YYYY')
```

I confirm NLS_DATE_FORMAT = DD.MM.YYYY

I need expertise help to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: [DATE Data Type](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-5405B652-C30E-4F4F-9D33-9A4CB2110F1B): **For each** `DATE` value, Oracle stores the following information: **year, month, day, hour, minute, and second.**

Comment: I expect the output to be stored as "31/08/2023" and remove hour, minute and second. Is there any possibility to store as "DD/MM/YYYY" format.

Comment: Neither date nor timestamp is "stored" as anything human-readable. Any string you can understand is always, always, always the result of a conversion to string function at the time of display, whether explicit or implicit. If you only want to see a date, ensure your format asks for only the date portion. Use `TO_CHAR` in your above attempts *at select time* (not at insert time) and you'll get what you want.

Comment: "31/08/2023", "2023-08-31" and "The thirty first of August 2023" are the same point in time (dates). There's no any format for date (point in time). You may want different ways to see this value but it has nothing to do with date value itself

Comment: ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YYYY  HH24:MI:SS';

Comment: You can use the [`dump()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/DUMP.html) function along with https://stackoverflow.com/a/13568348/230471 to learn how dates and timestamps are actually stored. I'm not sure why you think a timestamp is stored as "31-AUG-23 12.00.00.000000000 AM", because it absolutely is not.

Comment: Just to add, a `number` column containing `12.34` will be stored as three bytes `193,13,35`. It may then be formatted as `12.34`, `1.234e1`, `12` etc when displayed by a client according to its settings. As with dates and timestamps, internal binary storage is not related to display formatting.

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle, both `DATE` and `TIMESTAMP` are binary data types containing:

- Date and Time (7-bytes for century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second)
- A `TIMESTAMP` may also include fractional seconds (between 0 and 6 bytes depending on precision)
- A `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` will also include 7 bytes for the time-zone information.

For both `DATE` and `TIMESTAMP`, you will **ALWAYS** have both a date and a time component to the data type. It is also **NEVER** stored in any particular human-readable format (they are stored as binary values).

> Is there any possibility to store as "DD/MM/YYYY" format.

No, as mentioned above, it is stored in a binary format that always has a time component.

---

When you use `TO_DATE('31/08/2023','DD/MM/YYYY')`, you are creating a `DATE` where the date component is `2023-08-31` and the time component is `00:00:00`. When Oracle inserts this into a `TIMESTAMP` column then it will implicitly cast from a `DATE` to a `TIMESTAMP` and set any fractional seconds to `0`. This is what is inserted into the database column and you **CANNOT** change the format of the stored data (as mentioned, it is binary data without any particular human-readable format)

---

What you want to do is to change how the `TIMESTAMP` is **displayed** (rather than trying to change how it is stored).

You can either:

1. Use `TO_CHAR(log_date, 'DD.MM.YYYY')` in the `SELECT` query when you view the contents of the table; or
2. Change the preferences of your client application so that it displays `TIMESTAMP`s in a different format. You will need to refer to the documentation for your client application as to how to do this.

   If you are using one of Oracle's client applications (i.e. SQL*Plus, SQL Developer or SQLCl) then you can change the `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT`:

   ```slq
   ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'DD.MM.YYYY';
   ```

   But that would change how it displays **ALL** `TIMESTAMP`s and always hide the time component (and you probably do not want to do that, just use `TO_CHAR` instead).

---

As an aside, if you are not using any time components I would question why you are using a `TIMESTAMP(9)` data type that stores fractional seconds with 9-digits of precision? If you are not using the time component then use either `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP(0)` as they will both be stored in 7-bytes.

Comment: I understand your point. This clears my doubt on how DATE/TIME is stored on Oracle tables. NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT plays important part in storing the values. Currently, this parameter is set as “DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM". In order to insert the DATE as "DD/MM/YYYY" format, i will have to set this parameter to "DD/MM/YYYY" format. Also, i dont see the usage of TIME fields in my tables. So, i will also request DBA to change the datatype from TIMESTAMP to DATE along with the change of NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT parameter. Thank you very much for clearing my doubts :)

Comment: @PrakashSomasundaram You appear to have missed the point. The `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` plays no part in inserting data into `TIMESTAMP`s; it is only used when the database implicitly converts from a `TIMESTAMP` to a string (or vice versa) and by some client applications for display purposes. You are not relying on implicit conversions when you insert a `DATE`. You do not need to talk to a DBA to change that setting; you should be able to modify your own session parameters.

Answer (score -1):

The behavior you're observing is due to the nature of the `TIMESTAMP` datatype in Oracle. When you insert a `DATE` value into a `TIMESTAMP` column, Oracle will implicitly convert the `DATE` to a `TIMESTAMP` by adding the default time of midnight (`00:00:00.000000000`). This is why you're seeing "31-AUG-23 12.00.00.000000000 AM" in the output.

The format "31/08/2023" is a representation of the date, and the actual stored value in the database doesn't have this format. The format you see when querying the table is determined by the session's NLS settings or the default settings of the tool you're using to query the database.

If you truly want to store only the date without the time component, you should use the `DATE` datatype for the `LOGDATE` column. If you need to use the `TIMESTAMP` datatype for other reasons (e.g., to store fractional seconds), then you'll always have the time component, even if it's just midnight.

Here are some clarifications and suggestions:

1. Changing the Column Datatype: If you only want to store the date and not the time, consider changing the `LOGDATE` column datatype to `DATE`. This will store only the date without the time component.
2. Displaying the Date: If you want to display the date in a specific format when querying, you can use the `TO_CHAR` function:

   ```sql
   SELECT TO_CHAR(LOGDATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') FROM ABC.TABLE1;
   ```
3. NLS_DATE_FORMAT: The `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` setting affects the default display format for dates, but it doesn't change the actual stored value. If you're using a tool like SQL*Plus, you can set the date format for your session:

   ```sql
   ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='DD/MM/YYYY';
   ```

   After setting this, when you query the `LOGDATE` column, it should display in the format "31/08/2023" if the column datatype is `DATE`.
4. Inserting Values: When inserting values, you only need to use the `TO_DATE` function:

   ```sql
   Insert into ABC.TABLE1 (SYSTEM, NAME, EMPID, CONNECTIONID, LOGDATE, DEPT) 
   values ('B11','PATRICK','G18','B11A1',TO_DATE('31/08/2023','DD/MM/YYYY'),'ING');
   ```

   The other formats you tried (`trunc` and `DATE`) are not appropriate for this use case.

In summary, if you want to store only the date without the time, use the `DATE` datatype. If you need to store the time component, then you'll have to accept the default time of midnight when inserting dates without a specific time.

Comment: "If you truly want to store only the date without the time component, you should use the `DATE` datatype" In Oracle, a `DATE` **ALWAYS** has a time component (your client application may chose not to display the time component but it is always there).